# UnsupportedOperationException when calling JDBC OracleDriver

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am using the following piece of code inorder to connect

```
 Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
```

but it is showing the following error:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:
>
> Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 1.6 is not supported by this driver. Use the sqljdbc4.jar class library, which provides support for JDBC 4.0.

But the driver I used is **sqljdbc4.jar** only. What to do now..??